# How to use a custom build script (build.sh) in openshift buildconfig rather than using inbuilt S2I?

Tags: build, openshift-origin

I created a simple buildconfig on openshift and it is working perfectly. But I want to execute a build script before running the docker build command. This is the buildconfig I created :

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "BuildConfig"
metadata:
  name: "keycloak-build"
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: "ImageStreamTag"
      name: "keycloak:latest"
  source:
    git:
      uri: "https://git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/key"
    sourceSecret:
      name: "codecommit_secret"
    type: "Git"
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
        dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the default `assemble` script by adding a `.s2i/bin/assemble` file in your git repo.

This will take precedence over the default script.

See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/s2i_images/customizing_s2i_images.html